# Different font size when running emacs and emacsclient

Tags: emacs, fonts

In my .emacs file, I setup font size like:

```
(set-default-font "Source Code Pro 10")
```

If I run emacs as standalone program, i.e. emacs aFile.c, the font size looks correct.
But if I run emacs using emacsclient , i.e. like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor="" -c "$@"
```

the font size is 13, instead of 10, i specified in 10.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Source Code Pro-14")))
```

**Edit**

I'm sorry for the missing double quote typo. I've fixed it. It works on my system.

I also tried `add-to-list`, it won't set the font that @michael desired. Since @michael is using emacsclient, I see no problem in using `setq`.

Please @michael try and see whether it will work.

Comment: Normally, `add-to-list` is used *instead of* `setq` so as not to wipe out everything in the `default-fame-alist`.  Your solution wipes it out and places only one-half of the font cons cell in its place.  The `default-frame-alist` is a list of things.  And, normally the elements of that list are cons cells -- like this, where the `car` of the cons cell is `font` -- e.g., `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"))`  And, you have only one double quote . . .

Comment: As to a GUI version of Emacs on OSX with Emacs Trunk (October 2014), the `default-frame-alist` for the *font* also fails to catch the initial frame, but it works for subsequent frames.  To handle the initial frame, I use:  `(set-face-attribute 'default (selected-frame) :font "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")`.  I haven't tested this with `emacsclient`.